# DragDropManager How to prevent from adding incoming element to list?

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, grid, telerik

Currently my page consist of two grid side by side, each of the grid binding a list, says **GridA** binding **ListA** and **GridB** binding **ListB**.

Both of the grid implemented `Telerik DragDropManager`. In most cases everything works fine, user can simply drag element from **GridA** and drop on **GridB** and both **ListA** and **ListB** will reflect accordingly.

Now I'm trying to make a checking on **GridB** so that whenever user drag an element from **GridA**, if this element existed in **GridB**, the element won't be added.

I noticed I can implement a `drop` function at **GridB** as below:

```
<telerik:RadGridView 
    ItemSource="{Binding ListB}" 
    DataContext="{Binding [someViewModel]}" 
    Drop="abc_Drop" 
    DataLoaded="abc_DataLoaded"
    x:Name="GridB">
```

And below will be my `drop` function:

```
private void abc_Drop(object sender, System.Windows.DragEventArgs e)
{
   var selectedItem = (T)GridA.SelectedItem;
   List<T> x = someViewModel.ListB; 
}
```

In order to investigate, I put a breakpoint on `abc_Drop` method. What I found is that, while I execute `abc_Drop` method, `someViewMode.ListB.Count()` still return `0` but once it finish, `someViewModel.ListB.Count()` return `1`. Hence my question, where should I do the checking and prevent element added into the list conditionally? What will be executed right after `drop` method?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer myself.

```
private void abc_Drop(object sender, System.Windows.DragEventArgs e){

    e.Handled = true;
    var selectedItem = (T)GridA.SelectedItem;
    if( /*condition*/ ){
        ListB.Add(selectedItem);
    }
    GridB.Rebind();
}
```

By using `e.Handled = true`, it halted the operation and I can now implement my own logic into it